# URL Rewrite not keeping full path

Tags: url, url-rewrite-module

I'm trying to use the URL Rewrite module for **IIS 8** to make sure all connections are https.  What I cannot figure out is how to maintain the full path for the rule.  I am new to using this so hopefully this is a simple fix.

I will go to a page like this : https://xyz.domain.com/mypath/default.aspx.

After removing the 's' from 'https', I get redirected to https://xyz.domain.com/default.aspx and the `mypath` path is gone.  I need to maintain this.

Here is the webconfig entry:

```
    <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Force http to https" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue after following an example online.  I changed the redirect url to be `https://{HTTP_HOST}/{REQUEST_URI}`, and it preserved the full URL in the redirected request.

For reference, see the online docs [URL Rewrite Module Configuration Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<!-- Require HTTPS -->
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```